# When using Vue 3 with VTK.js why doesn't the render display on the screen?

Tags: vue.js, vtk, vtk.js

When following the official [VTK.js/Vue.js tutorial](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/docs/vtk_vue.html) (and using a recent 3.x release) why doesn't the cone render in the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

In the default CSS shipped with Vue the `base.css` file forces all elements to have the style:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

The `position` being set to `relative` causes the `canvas` on which the cone is supposed to be rendered to be set to `0` for both `width` and `height`.

Commenting out `position: relative;` resolves the issue.